# Why does the jQuery validate email regex allow emails ending in "."

Tags: jquery, regex, email, jquery-validate

We love jQuery validate, and really want to keep using it.

However, one of it's most useful features is to be able to validate email addresses client-side... but the regular expression that it uses accepts emails ending in ".", which I didn't believe was valid and certainly isn't liked by our back-end systems.

I wonder if anyone knows why this particular regex was chosen or whether it is perhaps a bug?

The jquery.validate-1.8.1 code in quesion:

```
        // http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/email
    email: function(value, element) {
        // contributed by Scott Gonzalez: http://projects.scottsplayground.com/email_address_validation/
        return this.optional(element) || /^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i.test(value);
    },
```

Comment: It's a perfectly valid email. Actually, ALL domains end in a ".", which is optional.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`stackoverflow.com.` is perfectly valid - actually it's the only way to make a domain name a [Fully Qualified Domain Name.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) Technically, it's your back-end systems that are at fault for not accepting this (although I'm sure I myself have written validation code in the past that doesn't accept it either...)

See http://www.dns-sd.org/TrailingDotsInDomainNames.html for an in-depth explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I think this page will explain why the dot is allowed at the end:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name

> A fully qualified domain name (FQDN), sometimes also referred as
>   absolute domain name,[1] is a domain name that specifies its exact
>   location in the tree hierarchy of the Domain Name System (DNS). It
>   specifies all domain levels, including the top-level domain and the
>   root domain. A fully qualified domain name is distinguished by its
>   unambiguity; it can only be interpreted one way.
>
> For example, given a device with a local hostname myhost and a parent
>   domain name example.com, the fully qualified domain name is
>   myhost.example.com. The FQDN therefore uniquely identifies the device
>   —while there may be many hosts in the world called myhost, there can
>   only be one myhost.example.com. **In the Domain Name System, and most
>   notably, in DNS zone files, a fully qualified domain name is specified
>   with a trailing dot.** For example, somehost.example.com. specifies an
>   absolute domain name that ends with an empty top level domain label.
>
> **The DNS root domain is unnamed, which is expressed by an empty label,
>   resulting in a domain name ending with the dot separator.**